# Iterate through elements with DOMDocument & DOMXPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am trying to iterate through every child element of the containing `div`:

```
$html = '    <div id="roothtml">
<h1>
Introduction</h1>
<p>text</p>
<h2>
text</h2>
<p>
test</p>
</div>';
```

And I have this PHP:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$dom->preserveWhitespace = false;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$els = $xpath->query("/div");
print_r($els);
```

All I get though is `DOMNodeList Object ( )`

Having looked at [the IBM tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-xpathphp/index.html) I should be getting an array. What is it I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong query string, you should be using `//div`.

Iterate over the list [like this](http://viper-7.com/Gloyhb):

```
$els = $xpath->query("//div");
foreach( $els as $el) {
    echo $el->textContent;
}
```

Comment: Thats great.. thank you! I'll accept your answer when it lets me.

Comment: @beingalex - You're welcome - Just note that the `var_dump()` you're seeing can be confusing - See [this demo](http://viper-7.com/lZoBP4). Even though there are elements in the list, the `var_dump()` is empty, so don't rely on it!